# Apply Datatemplate for Datagrid autogenerated columns - Dynamic binding of Column Name

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, datagrid

I used the Datatemplate for Datagrid columns which is autogenerated set to true,  I would like to bind the column Name in Datatemplate dynamically, so that I can use one Datatemplate for all columns, is it Possible??

I have tried with DataGridTemplateColumn and DataTemplate, but it looks like DataGridTemplateColumn I have to create for every Column, so proceed with DataTemplate.

Purpose of using DataTemplate is, based on the column value, it shows the image.

## XAML:

```
<Image Name="theImage" Width="40" Height="30" Source="../Resources/Help.png"/>
   <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Col1}" Value="0,00">
       <Setter TargetName="theImage" Property="Source" Value="../Resources/pmIcons/minus-256.png"/>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Col1}" Value="1,00">
        <Setter TargetName="theImage" Property="Source" Value="../Resources/pmIcons/greenRoundTick.png"/>
    </DataTrigger>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Col1}" Value="2,00">
         <Setter TargetName="theImage" Property="Source" Value="../Resources/pmIcons/redCross.png"/>
     </DataTrigger>     
   </DataTemplate.Triggers>
 </DataTemplate>


<DataTemplate>
<Image Name="theImage" Width="40" Height="30" Source="../Resources/Help.png"/>
   <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Col2}" Value="0,00">
       <Setter TargetName="theImage" Property="Source" Value="../Resources/pmIcons/minus-256.png"/>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Col2}" Value="1,00">
        <Setter TargetName="theImage" Property="Source" Value="../Resources/pmIcons/greenRoundTick.png"/>
    </DataTrigger>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Col2}" Value="2,00">
         <Setter TargetName="theImage" Property="Source" Value="../Resources/pmIcons/redCross.png"/>
     </DataTrigger>   
   </DataTemplate.Triggers>
 </DataTemplate>
```

## Pm.xaml.vb:

```
Private Sub AutoGeneratingColumn(sender As Object, e As DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs)


        If e.PropertyName = "IsReadable" Or e.PropertyName = "HasValue" Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If


      Dim oGrdTemplate As DataGridTemplateColumn = New DataGridTemplateColumn
        oGrdTemplate.Header = e.Column.Header               
        oGrdTemplate.CellTemplate = CType(grdTotal.FindResource("test"), DataTemplate)
        e.Column = oGrdTemplate
```

Expected: The above code works, but I have 40 columns so I have to duplicate the same DataTemplate for 40 times. I feel its not the better approach. I would like to bind the corresponding Column name as Col1, Col2, Col3 etc in every Columns. Its there a way to bind in Xaml well and good if not in code-behind is possible?

I tried with `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=.}" Value="0,00">` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty room of improvement your design, for example you should have an `Enumeration` as your columns instead of 40 distinctive named objects.

But even with your current design, you can implement an `IValueConverter` that directly turns the value to the correct image URI and then you can bind the `Image` directly to your source Value through the converter.

Off the top of my head, untested:

Write a Converter:

```
<ValueConversion(GetType(Double), GetType(String))>
Public Class MyValueToImageConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        Try
            If CDbl(value) = 0.0 Then Return "../Resources/pmIcons/minus-256.png"
            If CDbl(value) = 1.0 Then Return "../Resources/pmIcons/greenRoundTick.png"
            If CDbl(value) = 2.0 Then Return "../Resources/pmIcons/redCross.png"
        Catch ex As Exception
            'this is okay for our purpose
        End Try
        Return "../Resources/Help.png"
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

Embed in in your Resources (`Window` or `Page` etc)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyValueToImageConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And bind your columns like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Col1,Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" />
```

You can then wrap this functionality into a `UserControl` making use of the ominous "Tag" `DependencyProperty`

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="StatusIcon"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:MyValueToImageSourceConverter x:Key="_conv" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Image Source="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:StatusIcon}}, Converter={StaticResource _conv}}" />
</UserControl>
```

And end up with something as neat and clean as this:

```
<local:StatusIcon Tag="{Binding Col1}"/>
```

You can then further improve this by replacing Tag with your own `DependencyProperty` called Value or something similar

Answer (score 0):

I have referred @themightylc answer then 
 I have added the class cls_PMImageConverter, 
`<local:cls_PMImageConverter x:Key="PMImageConverter"/>, 
<DataTemplate x:Key="colTemplate_Col1"> 
      <Image Source="{Binding Path=Col1, Converter={StaticResource PMImageConverter}}" /> </DataTemplate> 
<DataTemplate x:Key="colTemplate_Col2"> 
      <Image Source="{Binding Path=Col2, Converter={StaticResource PMImageConverter}}" /> </DataTemplate>`

etc till col40

and called this template in AutogeneratedColumn event as

```
Dim oGrdTemplate As DataGridTemplateColumn = New DataGridTemplateColumn
 oGrdTemplate.Header = e.Column.Header
 oGrdTemplate.CellTemplate = CType(grdTotal.FindResource("colTemplate_"+e.PropertyName), DataTemplate)
 e.Column = oGrdTemplate `
```

It works.. But still, its not dynamic rite? Can I improve this code further??

Comment: If you could bind your template directly to the DataContext of the column the name of the Property (col1-coln) would not matter anymore and then you would achieve what i think you're after (one single template only). But as i was trying to say: the real source of your problem as far as i can tell is in the model design - not the view.

Comment: My idea is to show the Datagrid in the view with autogeneratedcolumns, and rows and have functionalities like ediatable, Updatable, Readonly based on the Value. Sometimes number of columns in datagrid can also be changed, so that it re-create a column header, for that   Me.DataContext = Nothing '        Me.DataContext = prv_clspm. How can i use enum in this case. One more question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536183/e-editingelement-lost-reference-in-grid-celleditending-event